# Launch a program without waiting for return and without killing it when exit in C++

Tags: c++

OS: Windows
Language: C++
I'm coding program A for it to launch program B without waiting for program B to terminate. So let's say the code is like the following:

```
int main() {
    Launch program B
    MessageBox(NULL,"Program B is currently running",NULL,0);
}
```

The program should just start program B and send the message box at (almost) the same moment instead of waiting for program B to finish.

Also, I want program B to run as an independant process. If program A was closed by the user while program B is running, program B should still be running even though program A is not running anymore.

I don't want to use the system() function because it's slow.

Comment: On Windows you can use `CreateProcess` if you don't care about portability.

Comment: And if you're using `MessageBox`, you've pretty much tossed out portability already.  :)  So there's not much reason to avoid `CreateProcess`.

Comment: If you care about portability, use some cross-platform framework like [Qt](http://qt-project.org/) or maybe [Poco](http://pocoproject.org/)

Comment: @cHao Does CreateProcess() match my 2 conditions? Do I have to change an argument (parameter) for it to work as I expect? Here's my arguments:  
`(L"C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\ProgramB.exe", NULL, NULL, NULL, FALSE, REALTIME_PRIORITY_CLASS, NULL, NULL, NULL, &pi)`

Comment: What do you mean `system` is slow?

Comment: @Jon The time needed to interpret the string in system("") at run-time

Comment: Any method of invoking another process will requiring parsing a string.  And parsing the string is not slow.  The slowest part of this will be loading the other EXE, which will probably be a billion times slower than parsing the string.